# How to order two Textarea and Buttons

Tags: css, bootstrap-5

I got this form:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="mx-2">
        <small class="text-muted">Tablas contenidas en el archivo.</small>
      </div>
      <textarea rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="col-md-4 my-1 mx-auto">
        <button>btn</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 my-1 mx-auto">
        <button>btn</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 my-1 mx-auto">
        <button>btn</button>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 my-1 mx-auto">
        <button>btn</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <div class="mx-2">
        <small class="text-muted">Tablas seleccionadas.</small>
      </div>
      <textarea rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/qh8a5Lro/

I want to order Buttons in the middle of the two textarea's but the text on the textarea's is avoiding this. How I can fix it? And I wanna make it responsive.

Any ideas?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gBwM.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q3amm.png

Thanks for ur help!

Comment: Do you need col-md-4 inside col-md-2? if you just remove that col-md-4, your buttons should be centered

Comment: @JismonThomas that doesn't work, I add a Row class and mx-auto in col-md-4 inside col-md-2, but I cant centered in vertically.. And it's not responsive.